# Exception while configuring Spring Security plugin in Gradle Grails application

Tags: grails, spring-security

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [gsp] in context with path [/glippedserviceapi] threw exception
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: grails.plugin.springsecurity.InterceptedUrl(java.util.ArrayList, java.util.ArrayList, java.util.ArrayList)
```

Comment: use grails.plugins.springsecurity.securityConfigType = SecurityConfigType.InterceptUrlMap instead of grails.plugin.springsecurity.securityConfigType = "InterceptUrlMap"

Comment: Please, show your Config.groovy(spring security settings)